# Map container is already initialized error is shown at bottom of page

Tags: leaflet

I am showing markers on map using leaflet framework. Error message is shown at the bottom of page "Something has gone wrong. Map container is already initialized.. Please try again." when more than one markers is added to map. All functionality of markers works fine. If only 1 marker is added to map then this error message is not shown at bottom

```js
var map;
var arrMarkers = [];
var lat = value1[1];
var lang = value1[2];
var map = new L.Map('map');
map.setView([lat, lang], 6);
L.tileLayer('api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key={piKey}', {
    apiKey: 'trv87gvquv8yyfr4nrwgsdzc',
    maxZoom: 18
}).addTo(map);
for (i = 0; i < allpairs.length; i++) {
    var j = 0,
        k = 0;
    var newpair = allpairs[i].split('#');
    var text = newpair[0];
    var lat1 = newpair[1];
    var lng1 = newpair[2];
    var title = text;
    var title1 = '<h1> this is sample text </h1> <br></br> text';
    var marker = L.marker([lat1, lng1], 'showtext');
    marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(title1);
    marker.bindLabel(title, {
        nohide: true
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very high chance that your code is calling `L.map("containerId")` when it is adding markers.

`L.map` must be called only once per container.

Save the reference (e.g. `var map = L.map("containerId")`) so that you can re-use it for next markers: `L.marker(coords).addTo(map)`.

If this does not solve your issue, you will have to post your code to get further help.

Comment: var map;
             var arrMarkers=[];
                var lat = value1[1];
                var lang = value1[2];
                var map = new L.Map('map');
    map.setView([lat,lang], 6);
                
                L.tileLayer('https://api.tomtom.com/map/1/tile/basic/main/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key={apiKey}', {
                apiKey: 'trv87gvquv8yyfr4nrwgsdzc',
                maxZoom: 18}).addTo(map);

Comment: for (i=0;i<allpairs.length;i++)
             {
                    var j=0,k=0;
                    var newpair = allpairs[i].split('#');
                    var text = newpair[0];
                 var lat1 = newpair[1];
                 var lng1 = newpair[2];

                    var title = text;
                    var title1 = '<h1> this is sample text </h1> <br></br> text';
                    
                    var marker = L.marker([lat1, lng1],'showtext');
     marker.addTo(map).bindPopup(title1);
     marker.bindLabel(title,{nohide: true}).addTo(map);
             }

Comment: My code is pasted above. L.Map is called only once. L.marker is getting called in a for loop because i have to put markers on map based on lat and lang

Comment: There is an "edit" link below your question, please use that rather than posting your code in comments…

Comment: @ABHIJIT Could not reproduce your issue, sorry: http://jsfiddle.net/ve2huzxw/169/ Please have your issue reproduced online so that people can investigate.

Comment: Issue is coming up when i dont have scrollbars enabled on my Page where i am showing map. If i enable scrollbars on the page then error is not shown..

Comment: do you have any idea why error comes up when page is showing map without scrollbars and error doesnt come up when scrolling is enabled on page where map is displayed

Comment: Please make up a new question with your code that can reproduce the issue, otherwise it is impossible to know what may be your problem.